# Why do I get constant password prompts from Github now?

Tags: git, github

For years, working away with no problems.  Starting yesterday, here's what I'm seeing.

```
$ git pull
- password prompt, enter credentials.
Already up to date.

$ git pull
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/scottcwilson/TSG.git/'
```

Why did things change?  Will creating a personal access token solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PAT (Personal Access Token) would be needed only if you have [activated 2FA](https://help.github.com/en/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa).

If not, check your `git config credential.helper`, and see if you have a github.com entry in your cached credentials.

Comment: I do this, and it still says `osxkeychain` even though I removed it using `git credential-osxkeychain erase` *and* in the Keychain Access Utility.

Comment: @ScottCWilson That is OK: that means your credentials are cached in https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain. If you don't have a github entry, enter your password once, and then it won't ask you again.

Comment: Seems like it works for a while and then prompts again when I change repos.

Comment: @ScottCWilson it should not if this is set at global level (`git config --global credential.helper`)

Comment: I do `git credential-osxkeychain erase` and then `git config credential.helper` and it still says `osxkeychain`.  I do a `git pull` on one repo and it works fine.  Then I go to another, and it prompts me.

Comment: @ScottCWilson Again, is this set globally? (`git config --global credential.helper`)

Comment: Sorry, yes it is - it's set to `osxkeychain`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197456/discussion-between-vonc-and-scott-c-wilson).

Comment: Weirdly, it stopped happening just as abruptly as it started.  Everything @VonC said was correct, so I want to give him the points.